# Why the author said minimal and not minimum?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is the question I am reading its solution:

Let $x$ be a nilpotent element of the commutative ring $R$ (an element $x$ in $R$ is called nilpotent if $x^m = 0$ for some $m \in \mathbb Z^{+}$).

Prove that $x$ is either zero or a zero divisor.

I found the following solution on the internet:

[image]

1- But I am wondering why the author said minimal and not minimum.

2- Why when $m > 1$ then $x \neq 0$ directly, is this because of the assumption of minimality?

Could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: It's just the adjective for minimum, no need to overthink it.

Comment: What do you mean?  That's just grammar...an adjective was called for so the author used an adjective.  You can rephrase the sentence to call for a noun if you want to..."Let $m$ be the minimum of the set of values ..."

Comment: I mean there is a difference between a minimum and a minimal element in math and I meant to ask about this difference here @lulu

Comment: What difference is there?

Comment: Nor do I understand your (newly added) part $2$.   If $m>1$ then you can't have $x=x^1=0$ else $1<m$ would be the minimum (or minimal value if you prefer).

Comment: The author said "minimal" because he wanted to say "minimal". And in fact he's only using minimality, not the property of being the minimum. Is this an important subtlety? Probably not. Personally I would have gone with "the least" et cetera, but it would have been more of the same. I don't agree with the claim that "minimal" is the adjective for "minimum", at least not in the context of mathematical English.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio In the integers with $\leq$ as the order, minimal elements are always unique (when they exist of course), hence minima, but I see what you were trying to say (considering what happens when using divisibility instead as the order relation).

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I mean the minimal element means an element that no one less than it can satisfy the property and the minimal element could be more than once and it is not necessarily inside the set. On the other hand a minimum element is only one and it is the least element that can satisfy the property also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question has been answered in the comments.

As for the second question, it is indeed because of the assumption of minimality.
We assume that the **smallest** $m$ such that $x^m = 0$ is an $m>1$ so $x^1=x$ cannot be zero because we assumed that the **smallest** $m$ such that $x^m= 0$ is greater than 1.

I hope this helps!